# How to display to arrayList in MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am working on MultiAutoCompleteTextView so , i want to display username and group name.

> if i press @ then it will display usernlist.
>
> if i press # then it will display Grouplist.

how to set to datalist in Array adapter?

Code:

```
GroipAdapter   = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    copyAllGroupList );
edt_message.setAdapter(GroipAdapter);

MessageAdapter   = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    copyAlluserList );
edt_message.setAdapter(MessageAdapter);
```

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i made two different adapter with same type of different arraylist.and those adapter set into MultiAutoCompleteTextView.but i can see only list of last set adapter.i want to see two list as suggestion as per above condition.

Comment: update your question with code

Comment: no need to use two different adapter , do same like the google place auto complete textview, just compare the arraylist content with your textview data

Comment: Create a custom adapter. In that adapter's constructor, put a field to take the type you want to display. Now in getView() method, based on that field, display whatever field you want to display.